# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

I am a fairly beginner programmer, so excuse me if the solution to this one is fairly simple (Although I have looked hard into finding an already-posted solution). I am experimenting with object oriented programming, but get this error message when running the program "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" at line 14.

```
var Gladiator = Object.create(null);
Gladiator.prototype = {
  becomeGladiator: function(attack, defense, hitPoints, name) {
    this.attack = attack;
    this.defense = defense;
    this.hitPoints = hitPoints;
    this.name = name;
  },
};

var Human = Object.create(Gladiator.prototype); 
Human.prototype = {
  becomeHuman: function(attack, defense, hitPoints, name) {
    this.becomeGladiator(attack, defense, hitPoints, name); //Error here
};
var ethan = Object.create(Human.prototype);
ethan.becomeHuman(14, 12, 15, "Ethan")
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using the `prototype` at all? `Gladiator` is already an object. Then you'd do `Human = Object.create(Gladiator)`

Comment: I'm sorry, i tried that and i dont think it solved anything. In case I'm getting it wrong, would you mind showing me how the entire code would look like with your changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`prototype` is a property of functions (constructors) that it is used to setup the internal `[[Prototype]]` property upon creating an instance. `Object.create` takes a parent object and creates an object whose prototype is the parent object; you only need plain objects:

```
var Gladiator = Object.create(null);
Gladiator.becomeGladiator = function(attack, defense, hitPoints, name) {
  this.attack = attack;
  this.defense = defense;
  this.hitPoints = hitPoints;
  this.name = name;
};

var Human = Object.create(Gladiator);
Human.becomeHuman = function(attack, defense, hitPoints, name) {
  this.becomeGladiator(attack, defense, hitPoints, name); //Error here
};

var ethan = Object.create(Human);
ethan.becomeHuman(14, 12, 15, "Ethan");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you curious of why *your* code does not work, here is a short explanation:

1. `ethan` inherits from `Human.prototype` object.
2. `Human.prototype` inherits from `Object.prototype` instance because it was created using object's creation  literal operator `{}`.
3. So when you do `ethan.becomeHuman(..)`, the interpreter checks whether `ethan` has a property `becomeHuman`. It does not. Then it checks the same on the object `ethan` inherits from, which is `Human.prototype`. This one now does have a property `becomeHuman` so it gets called with `this` keyword binded to `ethan`.
4. Then in the further execution `this.becomeGladiator` is `ethan.becomeGladiator`. Now, `ethan` instance does not have a property called `becomeGladiatar`. It inherits from `Human.prototype` instance, which does not have property `becomeGladiator` either. `Human.prototype` inherits from `Object.prototype`, which neither has a  property `becomeGladiatar` assigned to it. You have checked through the whole prototype (inheritance) chain without success and this why you get your error.